# JSON service calling return nothing

Tags: android, json

I call method in webservice that return string "true" or "false" and take two parameters using the following code

```
String isLogedin = readTwitterFeed();
public String readTwitterFeed() {

        String Result = null;

        StringBuilder URL = new StringBuilder();

        URL.append("http://localhost:1539/WCFService1/Service.svc/Login/");
        URL.append(username.getText());
        URL.append("/");
        URL.append(password.getText());

        ///////////////////////////// 
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
                URL.toString());




        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(content));

                StringBuilder builder = null ;
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }

                Result = builder.toString() ;


            } else {
                 Result = "error";
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
             Result = "error";
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
             Result = "error";
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Result;
    }
```

but the returned string is always empty

any idea why it not return data, also it doesn't display any error (I display the return value on textview), also I set the permission for internet like that

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

and am sure that the service is running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Localhost` and `127.0.0.1` are `Android emulated device's` own loopback interface,In other words, you connect to android emulated device (not to your computer) by using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. if you're trying to access your development machine use `10.0.2.2.`

one thing in your code you did not intialize your `StringBuilder builder`

initialize it like `StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();`

Comment: what do u mean by post number the code now become like :   
  StringBuilder URL = new StringBuilder();
  
  URL.append("http://10.0.2.2:1539/WCFService1/Service.svc/Login/");
  URL.append(username.getText());
  URL.append("/");
  URL.append(password.getText());

Comment: oh my mistake remove port number not post . remove ':1539'

Comment: but it published using that port number

Comment: it doesn't work, I search in how to apply internet to my emulator

Comment: it say connection to 10.0.2.2 failed